Stub-Based Unit Testing 5 Read Routines
Requirements:
Following are the functions I need to test, along with the cases where they can fail:
* readlines_fread() can fail due to:
    - resize_buf() failure.
    - alloc_and_append_line() failure.
    - fread() failure.

* readlines_getline() can fail due to:
    - getline() failure.
    - resize_buf() failure.
    - append_line() failure.

* readlines_mmap_memchr() can fail due to:
    - fstat() failure.
    - mmap() failure.
    - resize_buf() failure.
    - append_line() failure.

* readlines_mmap_getline() can fail due to:
    - fstat() failure.
    - mmap() failure.
    - fmemopen() failure.
    - readlines_getline() failure.

* readlines_read() can fail due to:
    - fileno() failure.
    - read() failure.
    - resize_buf() failure.
    - alloc_and_append_line() failure.

Now I have to simulate out-of-memory conditions, read errors, invalid stream errors, et cetera. I have written stubs (I hope that's the term, correct me if I am wrong) for the above functions:
stubs.c:
#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include "../src/common.h"

#ifdef RESIZE_FBUF
    #define resize_fbuf              resize_fbuf_stub
    bool resize_fbuf_stub(FileBuf *) { return false; }
#endif  /* RESIZE_FBUF */

#ifdef ALLOC_AND_APPEND_LINE   
    #define alloc_and_append_line   alloc_and_append_line_stub
    bool alloc_and_append_line_stub(FileBuf *, size_t, char *) { return false; }
#endif /* ALLOC_AND_APPEND_LINE */

#ifdef APPEND_LINE             
    #define append_line             append_line_stub
    bool append_line_stub(FileBuf *, size_t, char *) { return false; }
#endif /* APPEND_LINE */

#ifdef FEOF                    
    #define feof                    feof_stub
    int feof_stub(FILE *) { return 0; }
#endif /* FEOF */

#ifdef FILENO                  
    #define fileno                  fileno_stub
    int fileno_stub(FILE *) { return -1; }
#endif /* FILENO */

#ifdef GETLINE                 
    #define getline                 getline_stub
    ssize_t getline_stub(char **, size_t *, FILE *) { return -1; }
#endif /* GETLINE */

#ifdef FSTAT                   
    #define fstat                   fstat_stub
    int fstat_stub(int, struct stat *) { return -1; }
#endif /* FSTAT */

#ifdef MMAP                    
    #define mmap                    mmap_stub
    void *mmap_stub(void *, size_t, int, int, int, off_t ) { return MAP_FAILED; }
#endif /* MMAP */

#ifdef FMEMOPEN                
    #define fmemopen                fmemopen_stub
    FILE *fmemopen_stub(void *, size_t, const char *) { return nullptr; }
#endif /* FMEMOPEN */

#ifdef READ                    
    #define read                    read_stub
    ssize_t read_stub(int, void *, size_t) { return -1; }
#endif /* READ */

Now in the test source file, I follow this pattern:

Define the stub I require.
Include "stubs.c".
Then include the relevant source file for testing, say "readlines_fread.c".

So basically, define macros for the original functions and replace them with the stubs that merely return the error values for those functions.
As a result, each failure case is tested for in separate source files, so for readlines_fread(), I have:
readlines_fread_test1.c:
#include <stdio.h>

#include "acutest.h"
#include "../src/common.h"

#define RESIZE_FBUF
#include "stubs.c"

#include "../src/FileBuf.h"
#include "../src/readlines_fread.c"

void test_oom_and_overflow_error(void)
{
    FILE *const fp = fopen("test/stubs.c", "r");
    TEST_ASSERT(fp);
    TEST_CHECK(!readlines_fread(fp, &(FileBuf) {}));
}

TEST_LIST = {
    { "test_oom_and_overflow_error", test_oom_and_overflow_error },
    { nullptr, nullptr }
};

and, readlines_fread_test2.c
#include <stdio.h>

#include "acutest.h"

#define ALLOC_AND_APPEND_LINE 
#include "stubs.c"

#include "../src/FileBuf.h"
#include "../src/readlines_fread.c"

void test_oom_and_overflow_condition(void)
{
    FILE *const fp = fopen("test/stubs.c", "r");
    TEST_ASSERT(fp);
    TEST_CHECK(!readlines_fread(fp, &(FileBuf) {}));
}

TEST_LIST = {
    { "test_oom_and_overflow_condition", test_oom_and_overflow_condition},
    { nullptr, nullptr }
};

and, readlines_fread_test3.c:
#include <stdio.h>

#include "acutest.h"

#define FEOF
#include "stubs.c"

#include "../src/FileBuf.h"
#include "../src/readlines_fread.c"

void test_read_error(void)
{
    FILE *const fp = fopen("test/stubs.c", "r");
    TEST_ASSERT(fp);
    TEST_CHECK(!readlines_fread(fp, &(FileBuf) {}));
}

TEST_LIST = {
    { "test_read_error", test_read_error},
    { nullptr, nullptr }
};

and same for other 4 routines.
Review Request:
After much searching, this is the method I found on StackOverflow. It does not seem very tidy, and has a lot of duplication, but works just fine.
Are there any problems with what I am doing? Are there better ways?
Note: Unnamed parameters in function definitions are allowed in C23.  Furthermore, I do not wish to modify the source code for testing. So no TESTING macro that'd define the functions to the corresponding stubs, nor do I wish to play with the linker.

I'd prefer a bit more granularity. This implementation tests only one scenario, in which all functions fail.

@vnp Yes, I thought about that. Perhaps I could move these stubs to the relevant source files and have different test source files for each failure case. That sounds like a headache.

Consider to define them conditionally (e.g. #ifdef FEOF #define feof feof_test #endif), and build the corresponding test object with -DFEOF. Requires a bit more of the build infrastructure though.

Just how strong is your aversion to "playing with the linker"? I'm sure you know that the linker becomes (at least partially) satisfied when it first encounters objects in object files, shrinking its list of "unfinished business". A second object with the same name in a library will be quietly ignored. Seems easier to keep real code separate from stub code, and use the powers of linking to assemble the executable that you want. "It's as broad as it is long...". Advise keeping the real code as clean as possible...

It seems you've described 7 different source files that differ from each-other by only one token and one string... Remember "DRY"?? This does not look like it will scale easily...

@Fe2O3 About the linker, I only thought it would be uglier. About the duplication, well, that's why I am here.

@Harith For better or worse, this is "Code Revue", so one's hands are tied... Maybe give it a day-or-two, then post something similar to SO main site asking for tips to "supersede" functionality of code by "inserting" selected object files AHEAD of normal object files in an "ld" command. It's more of a "How can I..." than a "Look at my code" issue. FWIW, I "stubbed out" ~60-70 "overlay modules" (1990-ish) in a monolithic DOS accounting app. Link time fell from ~5min to ~5sec. Some modules were deadends, but I could test the one I was working on immediately... Cheers! :-)

About scaling, there will only ever be about 23 tests in total, so 23 source files. :) But at least there are tests that all pass. And @indi will no longer find it garbage code. As he claimed, the worst testing library is better than no testing library at all. (I might be saying that to make myself feel better about the 23 source files, bear with me. :))

The tests seem to be including the source of the code under test, which I don't recommend.  It's better if you can link the exact binaries that you built for production, rather than something slightly different.  (Also, for larger code-under-test, compiling it so many times can slow your builds down).  I've no objection to including the source of the stub functions though, as they can legitimately be compiled differently for each test.
Be aware that defining macros with the same names as library functions is not permitted in a strictly conforming program - we're at least flirting with UB here, though I have no concerns about that leading to actual problems.
As you're finding, it's inconvenient to use these functions - for example, you ended up with many near-identical test files that differ only in a single line.  One possible solution is to use compiler flags to define the failure mode (e.g. -DRESIZE_FBUF,-DALLOC_AND_APPEND_LINE, -DFEOF, etc. for GCC or Clang) and compile from a single shared test source.
It's quite difficult to keep related tests together in one source file (but could be made easier by more use of #undef to make it easier to undo substitutions on subsequent includes of "stub.h").
The stub functions themselves are a great start towards isolating the code under test and controlling the results that it receives.
However, they always return failure values every time they are called.  As your testing advances, you'll encounter situations where you need (e.g.) the second malloc() call to return null.
One possible solution to this is to pair each stub function up with a means to control its success or failure.  The simplest version is a simple counter:
// Assign this count from test fixture before invoking:
size_t stub_malloc_success_count = 0;

// And the function is called from the system under test:
void *malloc(size_t n)
{
    if (stub_malloc_success_count) {
        --stub_malloc_success_count;
        void *p = real_malloc(n);
        if (!p) {
            // We needed this one to succeed, but it didn't,
            // so the test cannot be conducted.
            abort();
        }
        return p;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

How you get real_malloc defined tends to be platform-specific, so I won't go into details.  But you will be able to find more information elsewhere on the Web.
You could replace the test-and-decrement with an atomic operation.  But if you have to do that, you likely have a problem with the repeatability of your tests already!

"Re: One possible solution is to use compiler flags to define the failure mode." ==> This brought down the source file count from 18 to 5. There is a nea problem albeit, the makefile looks horrendous, I've posted it up for review. :) As of linking the object files directly, I did give that a try, but failed because the object files have been compiled with the original functions, and not the stubs, and the macros defined by me did me no good.

Oh yes, you need to be able to interpose your stubs library to link them directly (using the platform-specific techniques I alluded to).  Sorry if I wasn't clear enough there.

I see. I will play around with LD_PRELOAD on Linux later. For now, I made use of the C preprocessor to cut down the source file count from 18 to 1, as I have shown in my answer. I have learnt more about testing things than IO with this project. :)

One tiny quibble...
Existing code:
// stubs.c
...
#include <sys/stat.h>
...
#ifdef FSTAT                   
    #define fstat                   fstat_stub
    int fstat_stub(int, struct stat *) { return -1; }
#endif /* FSTAT */

#ifdef MMAP
...

The stubs.c file is only for the coder(s) to read/work with. They are experts in their field.

Suggest more localisation of elements that are in-/ex-cluded from each build:
// stubs.c
...
#ifdef FSTAT

#   include <sys/stat.h> // needed for this prototype

    #define fstat                   fstat_stub
    int fstat_stub(int, struct stat *) { return -1; }
#endif


#ifdef MMAP

No need to mark the end of the first #ifdef/#endif. If the code looks congested, two blank lines between blocks can aid visual "chunking" and readability. (I've used two unnecessary blank lines to make the relocated #include stand out for this answer...

I won't repeat that lecture on not using #include inside header files.
As presented here, there will be only 1 (of 7) dedicated source file related to stat().
Its 6 brethren have no use for struct stat or its handler function.
Suggest that source file is the correct place for #include <sys/stat.h>.
Place that ahead of #include "stubs.c", and all will be well.

While not required, providing informative (but disregarded) names for each function parameter in the prototypes helps the reader distinguish the purpose of each parameter. Not required, but a nice-nice aid to comprehension when one sees only the function signature.

"Re: While not required, providing informative (but disregarded) names for each function parameter in the prototypes helps the reader distinguish the purpose of each parameter. Not required, but a nice-nice aid to comprehension when one sees only the function signature." ==> You're right, but I didn't wish to precede each parameter with [[maybe_unused]] or cast them all to (void). Else my compiler would have shouted like an angry person, all red. Good idea about the includes. Thanks.

@Harith ... OR, just use x = x; y = y; z = z; so all parameters are used in the stub. (const might be tricky.... Hmmm....) Crude, but may be effective... :-)

@Harith I'm not up-to-speed at all with [[maybe_unused]], but... My suggestion was for the header file's function prototypes. The code file's function bodies are another issue, but, again, my stomach doesn't like seeing just 'datatype' without a 'name' that hints at the purpose of the parameter... It's your decision, of course... :-)

Might like this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/attributes

My impression of "getting the grammar right". Stagnation is death; but I'm glad I don't have to write absolutely bulletproof C code that begins to look like COBOL used to... "Sheesh! When are we ever going to get to the end of the function signature and begin to see some actual logic happening??!!" Cheers! :-)

Problem: We have 18 similar source files that only differ in include directives, and the read routine being tested, and the name of the function that is testing the routines.
We shall attempt to bring the source file count down to 5 first, one for each read routine, and then attempt to bring it down to a single source file, one for all read routines.

Part 1:
Each test function has been named differently, say test_overflow_error(), test_read_error(), test_oom_and_overflow_error(), et cetera. They all test for failure.
So the first simplification we can make is rename them all to test_readlines_{{function_name}}_failure().
Going forward, the template for the source file names for each read routine is:
test_readlines_{{routine_name}}_failure1.c
test_readlines_{{routine_name}}_failure2.c
test_readlines_{{routine_name}}_failure3.c

and so on. 1, 2, and 3 do not hold much meaning. Let's remove these source files and just keep the first one (the one with 1 in it), and rename it to test_readlines_fread_failure.c for the readlines_fread() routine.
Now we can make use of the build system to do more work for us (after first removing the stub macro FEOF defined in the source file):
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DFEOF src/common.c readlines/test_readlines_fread_failure.c -o test_readlines_fread_failure_feof
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DRESIZE_FBUF src/common.c readlines/test_readlines_fread_failure.c -o test_readlines_fread_failure_resize_fbuf
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DALLOC_AND_APPEND_LINE src/common.c readlines/test_readlines_fread_failure.c -o test_readlines_fread_failure_alloc_and_append_line

This takes care of the first read routine, which had 3 test sources. Now it has one.
Do the same for the other 4 read routines, and you'd end up with only 5 test sources.

Part 2:
There is still much code duplication in the remaining source files. Each source file now has the same contents, except for include directives, and the read routine being tested, and the test entry in the TEST_LIST array that the acutest library expects.
In the below code, we require:
#include "../src/readlines_fread.h"

void test_readlines_fread_failure(void)
{
    ...
    TEST_CHECK(readlines_fread(..));
    ...
}

TEST_LIST = {
    { "test_readlines_fread_failure", test_readlines_fread_failure },
    { nullptr, nullptr }
};

each instance of fread to be replaced with getline, mmap_getline, mmap_memchr, and read for different builds.
Now let's remove 4 out of the 5 remaining source files and use the C preprocessor to simplify things for us.
For the includes, we can simply do:
#ifdef WITH_FREAD
    #define TESTME readlines_fread
    #include "../src/readlines_fread.c"
#elifdef WITH_GETLINE
    #define TESTME readlines_getline
    #include "../src/readlines_getline.c"
#elifdef WITH_MMAP_GETLINE
    #define TESTME readlines_mmap_getline
    #include "../src/readlines_getline.c"
    #include "../src/readlines_mmap_getline.c"
#elifdef WITH_MMAP_MEMCHR
    #define TESTME readlines_mmap_memchr
    #include "../src/readlines_mmap_memchr.c"
#elifdef WITH_READ
    #define TESTME readlines_read
    #include "../src/readlines_read.c"
#else
    #error "You need to specify one of WITH_FREAD, WITH_GETLINE,"
           "WITH_MMAP_GETLINE, WITH_MMAP_MEMCHR, or WITH_READ."
#endif

Now we need to tackle the test function name. We will use the TESTME macro we have defined for it.
#define CONCAT_INDIRECT(a, b, c)    a ## b ## c
#define CONCAT(a, b, c)             CONCAT_INDIRECT(a, b, c)

void CONCAT(test_, TESTME, _failure)(void)
{
    ...
}

## is the token pasting operator, it concatenates the tokens. We need an extra level of redirection because ## does not expand its operands. See: C: Expand Macro With Token Pasting.
Note that ## is only valid in a macro definition. We can not do:
void test_ ## TESTME ## _failure(void)

This applies to the single # mentioned below as well.
The call to the actual function in the TEST_CHECK() macro now becomes:
TEST_CHECK(!TESTME(fp, &fbuf));

Lastly, we shall tackle the test function's entry in the TEST_LIST array:
#define STRINGIFY_INDIRECT(x)    #x
#define STRINGIFY(x)             STRINGIFY_INDIRECT(x)

TEST_LIST = {
    { "test_" STRINGIFY(TESTME) "_failure", CONCAT(test_, TESTME, _failure },
    { nullptr, nullptr },
};

A single # in a macro definition will create a string from the given argument. We require one level of indirection for the same reason for # here that we did for ##. See: # and ## in macros.
Now we need to make a single change to the build commands, add -DWITH_FREAD, -DWITH_RESIZE_FBUF, et cetera for each test executable.
And voila! We brought down source files from 18 to 1, or the LOC from 400 to under 50.
This is how the complete code can look:
#include <stdio.h>

#include "cread/src/acutest.h"
#include "cread/src/stubs.c"

#include "cread/src/FileBuf.h"

#ifdef WITH_FREAD
    #define TESTME readlines_fread
    #include "../src/readlines_fread.c"
#elifdef WITH_GETLINE
    #define TESTME readlines_getline
    #include "../src/readlines_getline.c"
#elifdef WITH_MMAP_GETLINE
    #define TESTME readlines_mmap_getline
    #include "../src/readlines_getline.c"
    #include "../src/readlines_mmap_getline.c"
#elifdef WITH_MMAP_MEMCHR
    #define TESTME readlines_mmap_memchr
    #include "../src/readlines_mmap_memchr.c"
#elifdef WITH_READ
    #define TESTME readlines_read
    #include "../src/readlines_read.c"
#else
    #error "You need to specify one of WITH_FREAD, WITH_GETLINE,"
           "WITH_MMAP_GETLINE, WITH_MMAP_MEMCHR, or WITH_READ."
#endif

#define STRINGIFY_INDIRECT(x)       #x
#define STRINGIFY(x)                STRINGIFY_INDIRECT(x)

#define CONCAT_INDIRECT(a, b, c)    a ## b ## c
#define CONCAT(a, b, c)             CONCAT_INDIRECT(a, b, c)

void CONCAT(test_, TESTME, _failure)(void)
{
    FILE *const fp = fopen("test/stubs.c", "r");
    TEST_ASSERT(fp);
    TEST_CHECK(!TESTME(fp, &(FileBuf) {}));
}

TEST_LIST = {
    { "test_"  STRINGIFY(TESTME) "_failure",  CONCAT(test_, TESTME, _failure) },
    { nullptr, nullptr },
};

Note that #elifdef is part of C23. Code prior to C23 can use #elif defined.
Now the commands for building the test executables for readlines_fread() become:
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_FREAD -DFEOF src/common.c readlines/test_readlines_fread_failure.c -o test_readlines_fread_failure_feof
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_FREAD -DRESIZE_FBUF src/common.c readlines/test_readlines_fread_failure.c -o test_readlines_fread_failure_resize_fbuf
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_FREAD -DALLOC_AND_APPEND_LINE src/common.c readlines/test_readlines_fread_failure.c -o test_readlines_fread_failure_alloc_and_append_line


There is another, and simpler, way of skinning the cat here. See @Jonathan Leffer's solution here: Refactoring test sources. It makes use of the C Preprocessor as well, but quite less than we have here. For instance, if you have a macro that expands to look like a header name, you can use:
#include INCLUDE_FILE_NAME

So, you could compile with -DINCLUDE_FILE_NAME='"../src/readlines_fread.c"'. See Jonathan's answer for the full solution.
See also: What are the benefits of a relative path such as "../include/header.h" for a header?.
